# IIS 7.5 Application Pool Identity permissions to use WebBrowser

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, application-pools

We have an ASP.NET application which uses the [WebBrowser class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to generate screenshot thumbnails.

Moving it to IIS 7.5 causes it to fail due to permissions.

What files within Windows 2008 R2 do I need to give the IIS 7.5 Application Pool Identity permissions to use [WebBrowser class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Note: If I change the application pool to use Network service it works, but we would rather not.

Comment: Is your app pool identity in the iis_iusrs group?

Answer (score 0):

a) pretty sure it's not supported.

b) tried using the Load User Profile advanced property?

Answer (score 0):

You can use process monitor to track permission failures.  Basically set your app pool back then turn on process monitor and reproduce the error.  Then search for the word 'denied'.  That should show what it needs.

[Here's a quick video](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/iis/ProcessMon-Power-Tool-for-the-Windows-Admin-Week-20.aspx) to show how to do this.